# How can I boot in single-user mode for terminal with grey screen?

Tags: macbook-pro, terminal, startup, recovery, gpu

It all started when I wanted to sell my old Macbook 2011 and remove it from iCloud. I clicked delete my Macbook in iCloud. AND Whoup!! My Macbook shuts down and deletes itself....

I reinstalled High Sierra, unfortunately my AMD graphics card hasn't worked for years. But at that time the card was bypassed.

BUT NOW
I can't disable the graphics card via CMD+S.  It stops loading "HID: Legency slim 2".
I got the problem after the PRAM reset.

when I followed the instructions...
https://gist.github.com/cdleon/d1eff7246a25193304284ecec40445b0

NOW I also can't get into Recovery Mode with CMD+R.  Also not via internal or USB stick. I ALWAYS get a gray screen.

How can I disable the graphics card to set up the Mac?
I get prohibition symbol... i need a terminal! :(

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to boot in target disk mode to erase a machine that’s not healthy enough to boot to recovery. As you know, you’ll need to assemble an external OS and modify it to prevent graphics drivers to get around your failed GPU / logic board. Target disk mode often works in this case since only the firmware is running - no OS.

Both of these require you have another Mac running in my experience.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

Option is the startup manager you need if Internet Recovery or built in recovery fail.

Comment: Hm... thank you. 
Unfortunately, I only have an iMac 5K 2017 and Macbook Pro 2017 at home, but I don't have the necessary cables. 

In 2011 there is only one Thunderbolt 2 connection.

I just deleted the harddisk completely via Ubuntu. But that doesn't change anything on the VMRAM. 

Is there any possibility to change the boot USB (erase some text or something like that) so the stick boots and doesn't end up in the grey screen?

Comment: Not that I that I know of @yuenal You need the thunderbolt 2 to 3 adapter. Based on how much money you sell the Mac, may not make economical sense to destroy the data. Hopefully you can sell it for parts to someone you trust will erase the drive or has the parts needed to wipe it in your presence.